# How do I make sure certain portions of my page are unaffected by CSS changes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP page that allows a user to change the size of the page's font. However I want some text to remain unchanged no matter what the user set the font to.  I implemented a system where the user can choose between small, normal, and large font but some text needs to remain the same size despite the user's choice.

This is a sample of the CSS code I used for the "small" size:

```
.smallview{
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Here is the button created in PHP:

```
<a href="#" class="texttoggler" rel="smallview" title="small size"><img src="images/smallview.png" /></a>
```

Comment: @user2864740: Wrong; `!important`.

Comment: wrong, inline styles can be overridden with `css` using `!important` like `font-size:12px!important`

Comment: If the inline style is marked `!important` then css can't override that inline style with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be an easier ordeal for you if you only apply the smaller text in the areas that you want to change instead of applying it everywhere, then having to undo it.

so instead of the css you have, be more specific, like:

```
.smallview #content{font-size:15px}
```

or for multiple things:

```
.smallview #content,.smallview #sidebar,.smallview .etc{font-size:15px}
```